# Lockscreen notifications from iphone webpage?

Tags: iphone, safari

I was wondering if it is possible to send popup notifications from the iphone version of my site's webpage, sort of like Gmail does. The standard alert and prompt functions don't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. The gmail popups appear either because you have gmail configured with Mail.app, or because you have gmail sync installed.

Answer (score 1):

No. It has to be a native application that uses the Apple Push Notification service.